# Skip .NET Framework 3.5 language pack download

Tags: .net, installation, .net-3.5

I downloaded the .NET 3.5 SP1 redistributable package (231MB). On my machine I have more than 1 language pack. When trying to install .NET 3.5 SP1, the installer connects to the internet and downlands language packs.

If no internet connection exists, the installer has 5 (depending on how many language packs exists on my operating system) attempts to download (takes a lot).

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3):

try `dotnetfx35.exe /lang:ENU` (or the language of your choice) (via comments [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/11/23/download-microsoft-net-framework-35-sp1-standalone-full-redistributable-setup-installer/))